# New Relic JavaScript

Tags: localhost, html, javascript

I have a problem, I was logged in at New Relic, but didn't install anything. After that, my Chrome suddenly adds a weird JavaScript snippet to my localhost only, on AMPPS.

How to get rid of this, as it is disturbing me in my workflow?

This is the snippet:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE, requiresActiveX=true, Chrome=8" /><script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info = {"beacon":"beacon-3.newrelic.com","errorBeacon:":"jserror.newrelic.com","licenseKey":"a0d846db61","applicationID":"1585411","transactionName":"YwZTZUVRWBJRUkVfXlpMdV5DflMVc15fQkNbD11URR9wFF5VUGFeWgZfa1hVXU5jWV5BY1EQRF1DfF8SRA==","queueTime":"0","applicationTime":"447","ttGuid":"CBB2808590BE08C5","agent":"js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-292.min.js"}</script><script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),__nr_require=function a(b,c,d){function e(f){if(!c[f]){var g=c[f]={exports:{}};b[f][0].call(g.exports,function(a){var c=b[f][1][a];return e(c?c:a)},g,g.exports,a,b,c,d)}return c[f].exports}for(var f=0;f<d.length;f++)e(d[f]);return e}({"4O2Y62":[function(a,b){function c(a,b){var c=d[a];return c?c.apply(this,b):(e[a]||(e[a]=[]),void e[a].push(b))}var d={},e={};b.exports=c,c.queues=e,c.handlers=d},{}],handle:[function(a,b){b.exports=a("4O2Y62")},{}],"SvQ0B+":[function(a,b){function c(a){if(a===window)return 0;if(e.call(a,"__nr"))return a.__nr;try{return Object.defineProperty(a,"__nr",{value:d,writable:!1,configurable:!1,enumerable:!1}),d}catch(b){return a.__nr=d,d}finally{d+=1}}var d=1,e=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;b.exports=c},{}],id:[function(a,b){b.exports=a("SvQ0B+")},{}],YLUGVp:[function(a,b){function c(){var a=m.info=NREUM.info,b=m.proto="https"===l.split(":")[0]||a.sslForHttp?"https://":"http://";if(a&&a.agent&&a.licenseKey&&a.applicationID){f("mark",["onload",e()]);var c=h.createElement("script");c.src=b+a.agent,h.body.appendChild(c)}}function d(){"complete"===h.readyState&&f("mark",["domContent",e()])}function e(){return(new Date).getTime()}var f=a("handle"),g=window,h=g.document,i="readystatechange",j="addEventListener",k="attachEvent",l=(""+location).split("?")[0],m=b.exports={offset:e(),origin:l};h[j]?(h[j](i,d,!1),g[j]("load",c,!1)):(h[k]("on"+i,d),g[k]("onload",c)),f("mark",["firstbyte",e()])},{handle:"4O2Y62"}],loader:[function(a,b){b.exports=a("YLUGVp")},{}]},{},["YLUGVp"]);</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the RUM JavaScript snippet.
See https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/features/how-does-real-user-monitoring-work it also shows you how to disable it.
If you didn't enable RUM you probably should contact New Relic.
I'm not sure if it is enabled by default at the moment, I think yes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot find the part where to delete RUM?

Comment: Edit: The website doesn't show any applications, as I didn't add any. So I can't remove it at all from the website, I shot them an e-mail.

Comment: There is a tickbox on the Applications settings page: "Enable real user monitoring". If you don't have a Application setup that may be a bug and maybe it would be better to uninstall the New Relic agent then.

Comment: I never set up Real User Monitoring, so I ain't sure if I am doing something wrong, the most important thing is: how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Like I've said I think RUM is enabled by default. If you cannot disable it for some reason, then they need to help you. Removing the agent will turn it off for sure (and of course all other metrics will stop working too).